# Applying for a position where the department manager said he would be in touch

Tags: recruitment

I recently did some work experience, and the manager who was based overseas was very impressed with the work I had done, and mentioned that he would 'certainly be in touch if any position opened up for you'.

A new position has finally opened up, but since the work experience placement was over a year ago, I do not believe he may have remembered due to the number of staff he deals with (over 5000+).

What would be the best way to approach something like this.  Is there any way I can send him an email and give him a heads up of me applying for the position, or gain his recommendation?  Or should I ask if I can send in my application to him directly?  **I have not sent in any application yet - therefore, I do not believe it would duplicate with checking the status of an application.  How can I check the status of an application if I haven't submitted an application yet?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Comment: Not a duplicate.  This is a completely different question as I have not even applied for a position in the meantime.

Comment: How do you know the same manager is still there?

Answer (score 7):

There's no reason why you can't send an email alongside applying for the post.

Something like:

> Hi, I really enjoyed working for you last year.  It looks like a post has opened up, so I'm applying for it in the hope I get to work for you again.

He may or may not remember you, but this might serve as a reminder.  It also doesn't explicitly ask for his help, it just states the fact that you're applying and have a wish to work for him again.

If he wants and is able to, he might be in a position to help your application go through.

It can't hurt.